# Python Firestore convert DateTime to timestamp string

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I was wondering how I would be able to convert dateTime to timestamp for the firebase rest API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get firebase timestamp string

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_str = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```